# $resource function parameters in forEach AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this function I am retrieving every album from a list of albums:

```
options.albumsList.forEach(function (id) {
    var promise = $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/album/:album',{album:id},{
        get:{
            headers:{'Authorization':'Client-ID '+ options.apiKey},
            method:'GET'
        }        
    }).get().$then(
        function(value){
            albums.push(value);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
    prom.push(promise);
});
$q.all(prom).then(function () {
    console.log(albums);
});
```

What you will notice is `:album` is dependant on each `id` in `albumList`

This means if I wanted to assign the resource call to a reusable object like:

```
var call = $resource('https://api.imgur.com/3/album/:album',{album:id},{
        get:{
            headers:{'Authorization':'Client-ID '+ options.apiKey},
            method:'GET'
        }        
    });
```

And then wrap it with:

```
options.albumsList.forEach(function (album) {
    //Can no longer pass album id to each call
    var promise = call.get().$then(
        function(value){
            albums.push(value);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
    prom.push(promise);
});
$q.all(prom).then(function () {
    console.log(albums);
});
```

I can no longer pass the album id to each `:album`

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [resource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) (scroll down to the Return section), looks like you can just pass in a parameter to `get` that will replace the value in the URL.

`var promise = call.get({album: album.id})`

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thankyou. Is the same thing acheivable with `$http` as well?

Comment: Since $http comes from $q, I think so.